# How to fix 'An unexpected error has occurred. Please try again(7515006A)' at Google Play Store Application Publish

Tags: android

I get the error message: PlayStore App Publish

> An unexpected error has occurred. Please try again. (7515006A)"

when I try to upload .aab or .apk on Google play Console to create a new release. I don't what that means and please kindly assist how to fix that.

Error Image:

[image]

The loading keep showing and never stop

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's because of the new Google Play Console. Try one of the following

1. Clear Browser Caches and try again
2. If the 1st method not working try to upload in Incognito windows

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be an issue with the new Google Play Console UI.

An alternative approach to the one [Zi Sar K Nar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12336991/zi-sar-k-nar) suggested is to switch to the old console UI. You can do this by navigating from:

> Drawer > Use classic Play Console

Sadly, Google is killing the old console as from November 2, 2020. Hopefully, the bugs on the new console would be fixed before then.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Encountered a similar issue today except the code listed was 55E6FBB1.

I went back to the "Dashboard" tab and saw that it actually was uploaded despite the error, so check this before you start clearing caches.